# How can I center 2 button inside a div horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I've a div (1140 x 180) and I need to set two buttons inside, next to each other. Ideally, one button occupies the entire left side, and the other all the right side.
All this with "Flex", because I must respect the responsive design.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very simply by using the `flex` property like so:

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  width: 1140px;
  height: 180px;
}
.button {
  flex:1;
  height:100%;
}

<div class=“container”>
  <div class=“button”>first button</div>
  <div class=“button”>second button</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code snippet to understand that buttons are *horizontally* and *vertically* center.

Here is a [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) on how to align items with `display: flex`

**Snippet:**

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 1140px;
  height: 180px;
}
.button{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Button1</button>
  <button class="button">Button2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the  Claire answer. Here is a solution:

CSS:

```
.container {
        display:flex;
        width: 1140px;
        height: 180px;
        }


        .button {
            width: 50%;
            display: inline-flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

HTML(same):

```
<div class=“container”>
        <div class=“button”>first button</div>
        <div class=“button”>second button</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could place both buttons in a div and center that div within your outer div.

Answer (score -1):

Well, If the div has `display:flex;`, then you can `justify-content:center` . It will align all items to the center.

You can study more about justify-content from https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

If the div is `display:block` which is by default div styles. you can use `text-align:center` on parent div.